# Finding an equation form of a line from a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, linear-transformations

I have a matrix 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 25/26 & -5/25 \\ -5/26 & 1/26 \end{bmatrix}.$$

$A$ is a matrix for projection onto a line $L$ that goes through $(0,0)$.

I want to find an equation form of the line $L$. I know the line should be negative from reading the points.

However, I do not know how to find the slope of the line. Where should I begin?

Comment: Apply the matrix on any point. This gives you a point on the line. You know that the origin is another one

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ has rank one (why?), so its image (column space) is spanned by any nonzero column. Since this image is a lone through the origin, this gives you a direction vector for the line.